# Can other people deploy to my page If I've made the GitHub repository public?

Tags: javascript, github, deployment, github-pages, package.json

I've recently deployed a react project from the first time and also made its repository public.
I was wondering if is it possible for other to people fork and then to deploy their changes *to my deployed page* without my permission just because I've made the repository public? This is my first time deploying so sorry if it sounds super silly.

The homepage in the *package.json* file has the link to my page so if people fork it they will have the same link for it in their *package.json* file too; but does it mean that if they choose to deploy their version using scripts like

```
yarn deploy
```

or

```
npm run deploy
```

without changing the homepage link, it gets deployed to my page?
My guess is that they probably can't do that because the link is for my GitHub username only, but I still wanted to ask to be sure.

Thank you in advance!

People can't commit code to the original repository without me accepting their pull request so I'm not worried about them changing the deployed version through the original repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, in public repositories, any user can submit reviews that approve or request changes to a pull request.
Organization owners and repository admins can limit who is able to give approving pull request reviews or request changes.
After you're happy with the proposed changes, you can merge the pull request.
If you're working in a shared repository model, you create a pull request and you, or someone else, will merge your changes from your feature branch into the base branch you specify in your pull request.
https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm not using a shared repository and am the only one who can merge and accept pull requests. So what you're saying is that even if they fork my repository and run they deploy script while keeping my homepage in package.json file, it still would make a pull request for me to accept before it changes my page, right?

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. Yes, you are the owner, then you decide to accept the pull as a merge,  yes, correct. If my answer was accepted for you, please accept it :)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, checked it!